# Finely Specify Routes in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

So I have routes in my application that have similar URLs but need to go to different components based on certain values in the URL. I have tried to accomplish this via Guards but that does not seem to work:

```
{
  path: ':makeName',
  component: MakePageComponent,
  canActivate: [ValidMakeGuard]
}, {
  path: ':makeName/:groupName',
  component: MakePageComponent,
  canActivate: [ValidMakeGuard, ValidGroupGuard, ValidMakeGroupGuard]
}, {
  path: ':makeName/:modelName',
  component: ModelPageComponent,
  canActivate: [ValidMakeGuard, ValidModelGuard]
}, {
  path: ':makeName/:modelName/:year',
  component: ModelPageComponent,
  canActivate: [ValidMakeGuard, ValidModelGuard, ValidYearGuard]
}
```

Is this possible or am I missing something obvious to make this use-case work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created this functionality in the angular-router and there is an outstanding pull request and a NPM package you can use to test related to this. Add a vote to get this merged in & confirm if it's working for your use-case.

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/16416

The change provides the ability to fall through to the next route when a guard from a higher-precedence route returns false/rejects.

You can install to test in your project as follows:

```
npm uninstall @angular/router --save
npm install @angular/router --registry https://myget.org/F/snaptech/npm --save
```

Only difference between the two is this will find all possible matching routes and iteratively go through them until it finds one that passes all guards. If none do then it'll land on the '**' catch-all route

Answer (score -1):

The ":" syntax indicates variables. All of the variables are strings. So if you passed: mysite.com/xxx/yyy the routing here would not know how to match it against your routes.

You need more constants in your route configurations. Something more like this:

`make/:makeName/model/:modelName`

`make/:makeName/group/:groupName`

Then the router would match the desired route.

Also, since the `make/:makeName/model/:modelName` and `make/:makeName/model/:modelName/:year` go to the same component, you could just specify something like this:

`make/:makeName/model/:modelName`

to go to the ModelPageComponent and pass the year as an **optional** parameter.

Same with the group:

`make/:makeName`

to go to the MakePageComponent and pass the group name as an **optional** parameter.

For more information, I have an example app here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

Comment: So, perhaps I need to create a custom matcher to match not only the path but whether the value in that URL segment is valid. How to do that with a service though...

Comment: This answer changes the requirements.  Isn't the point of the "canActivate" to add additional "matching".  So if the if the guards don't match then the route doesn't match?   What's the solution to the problem asked?

Comment: Looks like there is at least a PR to address this: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/16416

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. The question was about finely specifying routes ... not about canActivate. I provided a suggestion that did not require using a route guard. Seemed well within the bounds of the question??

Comment: The purpose of the canActivate is to define whether a route can be activated. It is primarily to check whether the user has access to a route. AFAIK, it was not meant to be used to perform additional "finely specified" routing. From the docs: `Applications often restrict access to a feature area based on who the user is. You could permit access only to authenticated users or to users with a specific role. You might block or limit access until the user's account is activated. The CanActivate guard is the tool to manage these navigation business rules.`

Comment: I'm arguing that changing the routes to fit the way angular works without guards doesn't answer the question of making those routes work.  Routing is pretty limited if /xxx/yyy must lead to only one component or a custom sub-routing component.  Additionally, if access is "restricted" based upon a guard, the router still needs to do something, so it should go to another route. No?  Navigating business rules is exactly what fridder is dealing with.

Comment: How would any routing know that a route with simply "Honda/A32" would go to the `:makeName/:modelName` route or the `:makeName/:groupName` route? And how would a guard help if it could not even pick the correct route path to match?

Comment: After the url matches, it passes the route object to the guards, the guards evaluate everything they want to including the route's params (`:modelName`) and if the guard decides that that `:modelName` is not valid, it returns false, thus `canActivate` denies the route.  Then the next route matches the same params, but this time `:groupName` passes and it `canActivate` accepts the route.  Thus these are fundamentally two different routes even though they have the same URL structure.  Otherwise what is the guard for if it is does not operate additively for finer grains along with url matching?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I assume from the PR that this concept does *not* currently work like this? Hence it seems that my answer provides *some* way to make this scenario work now?